# Issue creating tableview with section headers from JSON | Swift

Tags: json, swift

**Essentially I have a tableview that is being populated from JSON, using the function below:**

The goal here is to make `allowdate` the header of these records in the table view, so everything needs to be grouped by the `allowdate`.

**But I keep receiving the error:**

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "ready_time", intValue: nil)

**The issue most likely has something to do with the function `fetchJSON()`**

```
var sections = [TableSection]()
var structure = [TableStructure]()

private func fetchJSON() {

guard let url = URL(string: "\(URL.url)example"),
    let value = name.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
    else { return }

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = "item1=\(value)&item2=\(value)".data(using: .utf8)

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
    guard let data = data else { return }



    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        //self.structure.sort { $1. allowdate < $0.allowdate }
        let res = try decoder.decode([TableStructure].self, from: data)
        let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: res, by: { $0. allowdate })
        let keys = grouped.keys.sorted()
        self.sections = keys.map({TableSection(date: $0, items: grouped[$0]!)})
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }

    catch {
        print(error)
    }
    }.resume()

}
```

**The following is what the JSON looks like:**

```
[
    {
        "person": "Jack",
        "allowdate": "March 26th 2020",
        "ready_time": "10:00 am"
    }
]
```

**To decode this JSON I am using the following structure:**

```
struct TableSections {
    let date : String
    var items : [TableStructure]
}


struct TableStructure: Decodable {

    let person: String
    let allowdate: String
    let ready_time: String

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case person, allowdate, ready_time

  }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

The issue I am having now is the error:

> error: Index out of range

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellID") as! CellExample

let item = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
structure = sections[indexPath.section].items

cell.testingCell.text = "\(item.customer)"
```

Answer (score 1):

As you've added the `convertFromSnakeCase` strategy the struct member must be declared as `readyTime`.

And the `CodingKeys` can be omitted anyway.

```
struct TableStructure: Decodable {

    let person: String
    let allowdate: String
    let readyTime: String
}
```

Comment: Please see my updated post, I applied the changes you recommended and now receive the error index out of range. Just so you know in the API the response is also now readyTime instead of ready_Time.

Comment: You have to return `return sections.count` in `numberOfSections` and `return sections[section].items.count` in `numberOfRowsInSection`. And delete the property `structure`. It's not needed.